# json to python dictionary covertion return in random order

Tags: python, json, django, dictionary

I'm converting json data into python dictionary using "json.loads()", but output of this is not in same order as original json data.

json

```
{
"cam":{
"cam1":{"dly":11,"val":12,"alg":13,"blk":14},
"cam2":{"dly":21,"val":22,"alg":23,"blk":24},
"cam3":{"dly":31,"val":32,"alg":33,"blk":34},
"cam4":{"dly":41,"val":42,"alg":43,"blk":44},
"cam5":{"dly":51,"val":52,"alg":53,"blk":54},
"cam6":{"dly":61,"val":62,"alg":63,"blk":64},
"cam7":{"dly":71,"val":72,"alg":73,"blk":74},
"cam8":{"dly":81,"val":82,"alg":83,"blk":84},
"cam9":{"dly":91,"val":92,"alg":93,"blk":94},
"cam10":{"dly":101,"val":102,"alg":103,"blk":104},
"cam11":{"dly":111,"val":112,"alg":113,"blk":114},
"cam12":{"dly":121,"val":122,"alg":123,"blk":124},
"cam13":{"dly":131,"val":132,"alg":133,"blk":134},
"cam14":{"dly":141,"val":142,"alg":143,"blk":144}
}
}
```

python2_7.py

```
import json

jscam=json.loads(json)  #printing this also shows datas are unorderd
cam_js=jscam['cam']

for key,value in cam_js.iteritems():
    print key
    for key1,value1 in value.iteritems():
       print key1,value1
       print('\n')
```

output

```
cam9
val 92
alg 93
blk 94
fl 91


cam8
val 82
alg 83
blk 84
fl 81

cam3
val 32
alg 33
blk 34
fl 31..............
```

its not same in the order as like raw json, in my case i need this in correct order to convert it into html table,
thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python dict is unordered, so you loose the order of your initial data. 
The workaround is to use `OrderedDict` from built-in `collections` module:

```
import json
import collections
ordered_json = json.loads(your_json_string, object_pairs_hook=collections.OrderedDict)
```

More documentation about OrderedDict [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).